# ruby-on-rails3, and select distinct using activereccord3

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Some methods have been deprecated with Rails3. 
It is the case in particular with the following call !

```
Error.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT type')
```

Is anybody have an idea, how to convert this call to an ActiveRecord3 valid statement ?

I found nothing on the web ...

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use the new [`select`](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html#query-interface) query method.

```
Error.select('DISTINCT type')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you seek to get a distinct set of returns against a PostGreSQL database, you must use:

```
Error.select('DISTINCT ON(type)')
```

and if your in the context of a scope, perhaps something like the following to ensure that you get all the fields:

```
scope :running, select('DISTINCT ON(campaigns.budget) campaigns.*')
```